# Firebase. Prevenir multiples conexiones del mismo usuario

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, login

Estoy desarrollando mi primera aplicación Android usando Android Studio como IDE y utilizo Firebase como base de datos.

Necesito que si un usuario se conecta desde un dispositivo, no pueda conectarse con la misma cuenta desde otro. Si alguien pudiese ayudarme se lo agradezco de antemano.

EDITO: No se muy bien donde incluir la solución que me da ...

Os dejo el código de mi LoginActivity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private Button btnLogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Get Firebase auth instance
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, conect.class));
        finish();
    }

    // set the view now
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUser);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);

    //Get Firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            //imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Introduzca su correo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Introduzca su contraseña!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //authenticate user
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // there was an error
                                if (password.length() < 6) {
                                    inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, conect.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Por favor, muestra algó de código que hayas intentado para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: No he probado nada, simplemente me di cuenta de que podía logearme varias veces al mismo tiempo con el mismo usuario y no sabía si existía esta opción. Pruebo lo que me ha dicho jirungaray y en el caso de qye no funcione, subo el código. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase ofrece una dirección dedicada donde actualiza el estado de conexión, puedes escuchar ese valor y mantener una lista de usuarios conectados. Entonces al iniciar la app puedes revisar si esa lista incluye al usuario actual.

```
//este es un path reservado de Firebase
    DatabaseReference conectado = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
    DatabaseReference estado = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("conectados/"+userId);

    conectado.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        boolean online = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
        if (online) {
                  //si se desconecta, eliminarlo de la lista
                  estado.onDisconnect().removeValue();
                  estado.setValue(true);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        //hacer algo
      }
    });
```

Si necesitas desarrollar algo más complejo te recomiendo leer [este blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html) con la forma de implementar distintas funcionalidades relacionadas.

Comment: Gracias por tu rápida respuesta,pruebo en estos días y te comento.

Comment: Si pudieras ayudarme a incorporar tu solución en mi código, te lo agradecería. No se muy bien donde incluirlo

Comment: Esto deberia ir en el primer activity ya que a aprtir de esto se va a definir si el usuario esta conectado o no.